# sqlite3.InterfaceError with cursor.execute()

Tags: python-3.x, interface, sqlite, pycharm

I am trying to loop through an array of returned values where `cursor.fetchall()` does not return a array of strings but `cursor.fetchone()` does, but only one value.

Code:

```
cursor.execute('''SELECT name FROM tv_shows WHERE downloaded=?''', (0,))

names_exist = cursor.fetchall()
print(names_exist)

if names_exist is None:
    return
else:
    for title in range(len(names_exist)):
        name = names_exist[title]

        print(name)

        cursor.execute("SELECT episode FROM tv_shows WHERE name=? AND downloaded=?", (name, 0,))

        episodes_exist = cursor.fetchall()
        print(episodes_exist)
```

And the error

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aoTw.png)

What I need to happen is both `cursor.execute()` functions need to return string arrays but dont.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out name is an array and what i want is at index 0

Fixed Code:

```
cursor.execute('''SELECT name FROM tv_shows WHERE downloaded=?''', (0,))

names_exist = cursor.fetchall()
print(names_exist)

if names_exist is None:
return
else:
    for title in range(len(names_exist)):
        name = names_exist[title]

        print(name)

        cursor.execute("SELECT episode FROM tv_shows WHERE name=? AND downloaded=?", (name[0], 0,))

        episodes_exist = cursor.fetchall()
        print(episodes_exist)
```

name has to be `name[0]`